# How to remove desktops from Ubuntu greeter?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, desktop-environments, unity-greeter

I was experimenting with various desktops and now I have many of them (GNOME on Xorg, i3, i3 with debug.log, MATE, Openbox, Ununtu) listed in greeter's gear menu, despite I have uninstalled most of them.

How to remove destops from greeter?

Comment: did you check the contents of `lightdm.conf`? (`locate lightdm.conf` to find it)

Comment: Please add output of `ls -1 /etc/X11/Xsession.d/` to the question.